# SAS - looping through the names of variables (columns)

Tags: loops, variables, sas

my problem is following - I have a SAS dataset with around 1000 columns and I would like to add another 1000 variables (columns) based on the calculations with the current variables.

The names of the variables are regular in this way:

```
    cft_1_00
    cft_2_00
    cft_3_00
    .....
    cft_1000_00
```

I would like to add new variables using the current variables. Because of high number of variables I prefer a loop to typing that by myself.

I tried following code, which did not work:

```
   data all3;
   set mydata.all2_08012016;

   do i=1 to 1000;
   cft_i_m200_var = (cft_i_m200 - cft_i_00)*100/cft_i_00;
   cft_i_m200_var = (cft_i_m200 - cft_i_00)*100/cft_i_00;
   cft_i_m200_var = (cft_i_m200 - cft_i_00)*100/cft_i_00;
   cft_i_m200_var = (cft_i_m200 - cft_i_00)*100/cft_i_00;
   cft_i_m200_var = (cft_i_m200 - cft_i_00)*100/cft_i_00;
   cft_i_m200_var = (cft_i_m200 - cft_i_00)*100/cft_i_00;
   cft_i_m200_var = (cft_i_m200 - cft_i_00)*100/cft_i_00;
   end;

   run;
```

What to add into the code to make it working ? 
Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Comment: You need to understand how SAS uses arrays.  I've closed this as duplicate to one question that is similar and shows how to create them; you may want to spend some time searching (either SO or the internet) for papers about how SAS uses Arrays, or just read the documentation.

Comment: thank you for suggesting me the way, this is actually very informative: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/97529_Using_Arrays_in_SAS_Programming.pdf